# Automapper Exception on construction

Tags: c#, exception, automapper, .net-6.0

I recently updated a project from .net5 to .net6 and now I get a error when trying to resolve automapper(11.0.1) from DI (or instantiating it).

Register:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MatchProfile).Assembly);
```

Instantiation:

```
var mapper = services.GetService<IMapper>();
```

Stacktrace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoMatchException()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.MemberConfigurationExpression`3.Configure(TypeMap typeMap)
   at AutoMapper.Configuration.MappingExpressionBase.Configure(TypeMap typeMap)
   at AutoMapper.ProfileMap.BuildTypeMap(IGlobalConfiguration configurationProvider, ITypeMapConfiguration config)
   at AutoMapper.ProfileMap.Register(IGlobalConfiguration configurationProvider)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.Seal()
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddAutoMapperClasses>b__12_2(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
```

is there a way to find out in which profile the error is located? Can I debug this in some way?

```
at AutoMapper.Configuration.MemberConfigurationExpression`3.Configure(TypeMap typeMap)
```

The error above is not really a useful tip to find the error, since the project is pretty large and I dont really want to comment out row for fow.

Created a unit test for this, which throws exactly the same error:

```
[TestClass]
public class MapperTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AssertConfigIsValid()
    {
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddMaps(typeof(ReportsProfile).Assembly);
        });

        configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

Edit:

ViewModels:

```
public class AnswerModel
{
    public ICollection<AnswerFieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AnswerFieldModel
{
    public Guid FieldId { get; set; }

    public abstract object GetValue();

}

public sealed class AnswerFieldModel<TValue> : AnswerFieldModel
{
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public override object GetValue() => Value;

}
```

MappingProfile:

```
CreateMap<Domain.Entities.Reports.ValueObjects.Answer, AnswerModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Fields, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Fields))
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<Domain.Entities.Reports.ValueObjects.AnswerField, AnswerFieldModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FieldId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FieldId))
    .Include(typeof(Domain.Entities.Reports.ValueObjects.AnswerField<>), typeof(AnswerFieldModel<>))
.ReverseMap();

CreateMap(typeof(Domain.Entities.Reports.ValueObjects.AnswerField<>), typeof(AnswerFieldModel<>))
    .ForMember("Value", opt => opt.MapFrom("Value"))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: Upgrade AM to the latest. Call `AssertConfigurationIsValid`.

Comment: Without having the mapping profiles it's hard to tell anything. I bet that the issues can be quickly solved by reducing to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error originated in `MemberConfigurationExpression.Configure()`, I have found the problem in the following mapping expression:

```
CreateMap(typeof(Domain.Entities.Reports.ValueObjects.AnswerField<>), typeof(AnswerFieldModel<>))
    //.ForMember("Value", opt => opt.MapFrom("Value"))
    .ReverseMap();
```

When this `.ForMember("Value", opt => opt.MapFrom("Value"))` is commented out everything works as expected.
In AM 10.1.1 this didn't throw an error though.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Open-Generics.html) on how to map open generics.

Comment: To avoid this problem you can use `nameof`, smth like `nameof(AnswerField<int>.Value)`.

Comment: Would `nameof(AnswerField<int>.Value)` work event though it is open generics? Can I just use any type to get the reference to Value? Does this even make a difference to just typing in "Value"?

Comment: Give it a try :)